# Como ordenar por duas propriedades em Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho a seguinte sintaxe e não esta funcionando

```
return View(trabalhos.Where(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name && 
                                 a.Data.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && 
                                 a.Data.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList()
                                .OrderByDescending(a => a.Data)
                                .OrderByDescending(a => a.HoraInicial));
```

Percebam que tenho dois atributos com ordenação **OrderByDescending**.

Neste exemplo a ordenação que prevalece é **OrderByDescending(a => a.HoraInicial)**, deixando sem efeito qualquer a ordenação **OrderByDescending(a => a.Data)**

Gostaria que os dois campo fizessem a ordenação primeiro por Data e depois da ordenação data faça a da Hora Inicial.

Comment: Você teve sua dúvida respondida? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 12):

Acontece que sempre que `OrderBy` é executado, ele **ordena toda a coleção**, ou seja, a ordenação anterior é desconsiderada.

Por isso, é preciso usar o método [**`ThenByDescending()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx)

```
trabalhos.Where(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name && 
                     a.Data.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && 
                     a.Data.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList()
                     .OrderByDescending(a => a.Data).ThenByDescending(a => a.HoraInicial));
```

Comment: "bueno", jbueno! rs... `+1`

Answer (score 10):

Utilize `ThenBy` na segunda ordenação se quiser a ordenação default (`ASC`)

```
return View(trabalhos.Where(
a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name && 
a.Data.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && 
a.Data.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList()
.OrderByDescending(a => a.Data).ThenBy(a => a.HoraInicial));
```

Ou utilize `ThenByDescending` na segunda ordenação caso queira a ordenação da data e hora inicial decrescente (`DESC`)

```
return View(trabalhos.Where(
a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name && 
a.Data.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && 
a.Data.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList()
.OrderByDescending(a => a.Data).ThenByDescending(a => a.HoraInicial));
```

Comment: 30 segundos na minha frente :p +1